# Custom renderer for Xamarin.Forms.Map not working for Xamarin.macOS

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mkmapview

I am trying to create a custom renderer for my map. It works good for iOS and Android, and now I try to make it work for macOS.

What i've done is that i've prepared the code and then i add breakpoints to see if the property every changes, and it does not.

So I wonder, what in my code is wrong in order to have this working? I have tried to change the `ViewRenderer<Map, MKMapView>` to a various different properties but nothing has been successful yet.

I usually use the Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps but unfortunately it is not supported for xamarin.macOS so going for the regular Xamarin.Forms.Map here instead.

````
namespace Project.MacOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : ViewRenderer<Map, MKMapView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {

            }
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }


        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        }

    }
}
```
````

Comment: Can you have a try with CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer?

Comment: Tried it, but not solving it unfortunetely

Comment: There is no map renderer in Github [Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS/Renderers/](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/tree/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS/Renderers). You can open an issue in Github or open a free [ticket](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6) for more help.

Comment: Ouch ok. I wonder what other route i can go then for Maps on Xamarin.Forms.MacOS. Seems super limited then to use Xamarin.Forms.Maps

Comment: I would recommend you to open a ticket to get more detailed info.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I am a little confused though. When i check the iOS code, i dont see MapRenderer either. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/tree/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers

Comment: When I share you the github link, I mean there is not a map renderer sample of Xamarin.MacOS in the Github.